# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select option[value=]

Tags: jquery

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select option[value=]

when trying this code. where i am making mistake?

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select option[value=" + $('select option:selected').val() + "]").css({
    "background-color": "#0000ff",
    "color": "#fff"
  });
  $('select').change(function() {
    $('select option')[0].value = $('select option:selected').val();
    $('select option')[0].innerHTML = $('select option:selected').val();
    $("select").val($('select option:selected').val());
    $("select option").css({
      "background-color": "",
      "color": ""
    });
    $("select option[value=" + $('select option:selected').val() + "]").css({
      "background-color": "#0000ff",
      "color": "#fff"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You're getting the value of the select when the page is first loaded, not when the user selects something from the menu. It probably has an empty default value.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify that to just `$('select').val()`.

Comment: This code seems very strange. When the user selects something from the menu, you copy its value and text to the first menu choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `select option:selected` .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select option:selected").css({
    "background-color": "#0000ff",
    "color": "#fff"
  });
  $('select').change(function() {
    $('select option')[0].value = $('select option:selected').val();
    $('select option')[0].innerHTML = $('select option:selected').val();
    $("select").val($('select option:selected').val());
    $("select option").css({
      "background-color": "",
      "color": ""
    });
    $("select option[value=" + $('select option:selected').val() + "]").css({
      "background-color": "#0000ff",
      "color": "#fff"
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="foo-bar">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  </select>
```